# Dataset reference in bibliography BibTex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am writing a Journal Paper which wants datasets to be listed in the reference as

[dataset] Authors; Year; Dataset title; Data repository or archive; Version (if any); Persistent identifier (e.g. DOI),

where "[dataset]" at the beginning is literal. The type of other references (articles, books, etc) does not need to be prefixed in this way.

and my bibliography file name is mybibfile.bib with following contents

```
@article{gross2010multi,
  title={Multi-pie},
  author={Gross, Ralph and Matthews, Iain and Cohn, Jeffrey and Kanade, Takeo and Baker, Simon},
  journal={Image and Vision Computing},
  volume={28(5)},
  number={5},
  pages={807--813},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

my LaTex code is using bibtex. Please giive your suggestion. My LaTex code is

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{xyz}
\author{abc}
\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\address{Research Scholar,}
\ead{abc@gmail.com} 
\begin{abstract}
jhjasvhjsh hjshjhjvhjsvh jjkjbkjbkjk jvkjvzjvkjvkj 
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
abc \sep xyz. 
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
Text-only mode can also be used for someone who is blind or hard of seeing and only needs the text read to them \citep{gross2010multi}.
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```